# Python Scrapy returns different url

Tags: python, web, url, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape `booking.com` with scrapy. The problem occurs when I try to implement pagination. I'm trying to get URL to the next page, but scrapy retrieves me different URL (I get it through shell), which resulst in "page not found" when I try to paste into Chrome. And when I try to put it into JSON, it doesn't retrieve any URL for pagination. Anyone has any suggestions? Maybe I should shorten the first URL.

I tried to set a `canonicalize=False` rule, but it didn't do anything.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BookingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "BookingScrape"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4Aomk4OkFwAIB&lang=en-gb&sid=163b31478fa340d233204d1dcbb259ec&sb=1&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.en-gb.html%3Faid%3D304142%3Blabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4Aomk4OkFwAIB%3Bsid%3D163b31478fa340d233204d1dcbb259ec%3Btmpl%3Dsearchresults%3Bcheckin_month%3D9%3Bcheckin_monthday%3D10%3Bcheckin_year%3D2019%3Bcheckout_month%3D9%3Bcheckout_monthday%3D12%3Bcheckout_year%3D2019%3Bclass_interval%3D1%3Bdest_id%3D15754%3Bdest_type%3Dlandmark%3Bdtdisc%3D0%3Bfrom_sf%3D1%3Bgroup_adults%3D2%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3Binac%3D0%3Bindex_postcard%3D0%3Blabel_click%3Dundef%3Blandmark%3D15754%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Boffset%3D0%3Bpostcard%3D0%3Broom1%3DA%252CA%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bshw_aparth%3D1%3Bslp_r_match%3D0%3Bsrc%3Dsearchresults%3Bsrc_elem%3Dsb%3Bsrpvid%3Da3bf35ea467d01b9%3Bss%3DKensington%2520High%2520Street%3Bss_all%3D0%3Bssb%3Dempty%3Bsshis%3D0%3Bssne%3DKensington%2520High%2520Street%3Bssne_untouched%3DKensington%2520High%2520Street%26%3B&ss=Kensington+High+Street&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Kensington+High+Street&ssne_untouched=Kensington+High+Street&landmark=15754&checkin_year=2019&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=10&checkout_year=2019&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=12&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&from_sf=1']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('CINE&OBRA&-1&29',), canonicalize=False), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for hotel in response.css("h3.sr-hotel__title"):
            yield {
                'hotel_name': hotel.css("span.sr-hotel__name::text").extract_first(),
                'link': hotel.css("h3.sr-hotel__title a::attr(href)").extract_first(),
                'pagination' : hotel.css('li.bui-pagination__item bui-pagination__next-arrow a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            }


        for a in response.css('li.bui-pagination__item.bui-pagination__next-arrow a'):
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.parse)
```

URL received through shell and which doesn't take me to next page against expected:

```
# Recieved:
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html" data-page-next class="bui-pagination__link paging-next ga_sr_gotopage_2_207" title="Next page">\n<svg class="bk-icon -iconset-navarrow_right bui-pagination__icon" height="18" role="presentation" width="18" viewbox="0 0 128 128" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M54.3 96a4 4 0 0 1-2.8-6.8L76.7 64 51.5 38.8a4 4 0 0 1 5.7-5.6L88 64 57.2 94.8a4 4 0 0 1-2.9 1.2z

#Expected:
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4Aomk4OkFwAIB&sid=163b31478fa340d233204d1dcbb259ec&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=10&checkin_year=2019&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=12&checkout_year=2019&class_interval=1&dest_id=15754&dest_type=landmark&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&landmark=15754&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&srpvid=7246436ad3b000a5&ss=Kensington%20High%20Street&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Kensington%20High%20Street&ssne_untouched=Kensington%20High%20Street&rows=15&offset=15
```

Comment: You probably need to figure out how the JavaScript code builds the actual request for the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my user agent name to Chrome in settings. So the web page I am scraping would not block me. Joseph, thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you need to specify that you want to use the href from the next button. Your code finds the button but it needs to get the link from the button in order to be used. Here is an example:

```
for a in response.css('li.bui-pagination__item.bui-pagination__next-arrow a::attr(href)').get()
```

You may have to fiddle around with the path but that is generally what is wrong.